# Attempting to use an array of Procs by using #.each on the Array but getting Error

Tags: ruby, each, proc

We have to write a method, chain_map, that accepts any value and an array of procs as an argument. The method should return the final result of feeding the value through all of the procs. For example, if the array contains three procs, then:
-the value is given to the first proc
-the result of the first proc is given to the second proc

- the result of the second proc is given to the third proc
- the result of third proc is the final result

I wrote:

```
def chain_map(val, *prcs)
    new_val = val
    prcs.each do |prc|
        new_val = prc.call(new_val)
    end
    new_val
end
```

When I run the code with the following:

```
add_5 = Proc.new { |n| n + 5 }
half = Proc.new { |n| n / 2.0 }
p chain_map(25, [add_5, half])          # 15.0
```

I get the following error on the line where it says new_val = prc.call(new_val):
undefined method `call' for #Array:0x00007fffd40268c8 (NoMethodError)

When I am using .each, its iterating over each proc stored in the array(prcs), so I don't see why it is giving an error.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`chain_map`'s second argument defined with splat operator, that mean remain arguments after `val` argument given by the caller will be wrapped into array.

But because you passing array of the procs as single argument `chain_map(25, [add_5, half])`, given array will be wrapped with another array in the method.

Don't wrap procs with the array

```
chain_map(25, add_5, half)
```

Or use splat operator on the array of procs if you build procs dynamically

```
chain_map(25, *procs)
```

Alternative approach by using `reduce`

```
result = procs.reduce(25) { |value, proc| proc.call(value) }
```